# Action Bar style not stretching and oriental view issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Issue 1: ActionBarTab is not fully scaled. It's center, but there are spaces on both sides. Even if I use 3 Tabs, there is STILL spaces on each sides. How do I fully scale them to the full width?

[image: Spaces on each sides]

Issue 2: How to change the color of Tab, and Tab Text when it's in Oriental View? I want to add more padding between each tabs because right now they are too closed to each other.

[image: Oriental View Tabs]

Here are all my codes:

```
  <style name="SM5Theme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBarTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBarTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/SM5Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background_bar</item>
    <!--<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>-->
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/tab_highlight</item>
    <!--<item name="android:divider">@drawable/actionbar_tab_divider</item>
    <item name="android:measureWithLargestChild">true</item>-->
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBarTabTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0FF</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SM5Theme.ActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#0FF</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed both of the problems.

Issue 1: I added

```
<item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
```

To both SM5Theme.ActionBarTabBarStyle and SM5Theme.ActionBarStyle

Issue 2:

On Resources, I created a new folder called "values-land". For those who are new, land stands for "Landscape View". I added modified styles.xml in that folder. So whenever it gets to landscape mode, it uses the styles from values-land folder instead of the original one.

Thank you guys for all your help, all of you were great. Couldn't have figured this out without any of you.